# onClick for Cruise List Heading using React

Tags: reactjs

At the moment I am trying to do a website on cruise ships using React in my spare time.
I have a working version on my Reviews branch, here https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/reviews.

However I am wanting to change how the Cruise Lines Page is displayed. 
I would like to have Cruise Line Headings across the page.
When a Cruise Line Heading is clicked it expands to show a List of Ships for that Cruise Line and if you click again, it collapses to show just the Cruise Line Heading.
At the moment I am a bit confused, as to how I can make this work and I have not got it working just yet.

I have been working on this, on a different branch called robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines: here https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines .

I have components called CruiseListHeader.jsx and ListofShips.jsx.

Just wondering if anyone can give me any advice on whether it's possible to do a ternary operator for this handleClick, that I have in my CruiseListHeader component?

It seems to me that the code inside my handleClick function is the code that causes the errors.

I think my state for opening and closing the ShipsList, so that's OpenshipsList and CloseshipsList, needs to be handled better. 
How can I better deal with this?

Does anyone have any ideas that may help me solve this problem and make it work.

The following code is from my CruiseListHeader component

```
import React from 'react' 
import {getCruiseLines } from '../api/api';

class CruiseListHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)  {
        super(props)

        //setting intial state for cruise heading and shipsList and initialize cruiseHeaders as an empty array
        this.state = {
            cruiseHeaders: [],
            shipsList: {isOpen:false}
        } 

        //binding methods for Cruise Line Headers and Handle Click Function
        this.setUpCruiseLines = this.setUpCruiseLines.bind(this),
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }  

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('cdm')
        this.setUpCruiseLines()
    }

    setUpCruiseLines()  {
        console.log('getcruiselines')
        getCruiseLines()
            .then(res   =>  {

                this.setState({
                    cruiseHeaders: res
                })
            })
    }
    /* There will be Headings for all the Cruise Lines.
        When a Cruise Line Heading is clicked, it goes to ListofShips Component and the Ships List opens up for that Heading.
        When user clicks on a Cruise Line Heading, when a Ships List is open, the Ships List Collapses.*/
    handleClick(event)   {

    // Maybe do a ternary operator here before open and close functions
    this.state.shipsList === isOpen ? OpenShipsList : CloseshipsList     

        OpenshipsList(event) {

            this.setState = {shipsList: {isOpen:true}}

            return 
                <div>
                    <ListofShips/>
                </div>
        }


        CloseshipsList(event)   {

            this.setState = {shipsList: {isOpen: false}}
            render()
        }

    }

    // This renders at the start when the page loads and also when you close a list

    render()    {
        return  (

            <React.Fragment>

                     <h3><button onClick = {this.handleClick}>{ship.cruise_line}</button></h3>    

            </React.Fragment>    
        )
    }
}

export default CruiseListHeader
```

At the moment, when I do a yarn dev I am getting the following error

> ERROR in ./client/components/CruiseListHeader.jsx Module build failed:
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (42:29)

I would like to get rid of this error and display the page like I have described above.

Comment: try to add semicolon ```import React from 'react' ``` first

Comment: You missed ```}``` in ```handleClick``` function

Comment: The error you are getting is due to the opening and closing curly brackets. There is two curly brackets issue. You are missing a `}` for handleClick. There is one extra `}` after `CloseshipsList`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with the indentations, but is `this.state.shipsList === isOpen ? OpenShipsList : CloseshipsList` supposed to really be `this.state.shipsList.isOpen ? OpenShipsList() : CloseshipsList();`? Note that `isOpen` is a property of `state.shipsList`, and then the parens to invoke the calls to open/close the list, and also the semi-colon to end the line.

I think you probably really want your `handleClick` to simply toggle the open state and then use that state value to selectively render the list.

```
const handleClick = event => this.setState(
  prevState => ({ shipsList: {isOpen: !prevState.shipsList.isOpen} })
);

render()    {
  const { shipsList: { isOpen } } = this.state;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {isOpen && <ListofShips />}
      <h3>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{ship.cruise_line}</button>
      </h3>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if it's possible to do this with this.state.shipsList.isOpen ? OpenShipsList() : CloseshipsList() or is it much better to do it similar to the way you have suggested?

I have my most up to date CruiseListHeader component here https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/client/components/CruiseListHeader.jsx

Comment: You could probably use either, but it depends on the situation. In your example you have two branches of logic that abstractly do the same thing, i.e. set a specific value in state, so it makes sense and is more DRY to have a single handler toggle this state for you. If for example you needed more complex actions then you could opt for the ternary pattern, but even then I'd advise to not mix state updates and side-effects, the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle or `useEffect` hook is the more appropriate place for them.

Comment: With the new code that I now have in my CruiseListHeader Component https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/client/components/CruiseListHeader.jsx, I am getting an error for line 63 in the console.
What code do I need to change or add to fix this problem?
The way of I have done the state seems to be correct, but for some reason the error is occuring with {ship.cruise_line} in the button.

Comment: What is the error? On line 63, what is `ship` for `ship.cruise_line`? It seems to come from nowhere.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ship is not defined and it says The above error occurred in the <CruiseListHeader> component:.
ship.cruise_line is meant to display the Cruise Line Headings as buttons. cruise_line is in my seeds file https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/seeds/ships.js.

Comment: @RobWilkinson Yes, it isn't imported or defined anywhere in the file so it is indeed undefined. It appears as though we're heading down the same path that you and Sultan have started down.  What is `ship` and where is it supposed to come from? Does it need to be imported? Is it part of the `cruiseHeaders` you setup when the component mounts? If the latter, then I agree with Sultan that it likely is an array, so maybe you want to render the whole thing but then you should map over them, or if you only want a single cruiseline you need to specify an index.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it appears to me that problem is in this part of code for CruiseListHeader

<React.Fragment>
                <h3>
                    <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>{ship.cruise_line}</button>
                </h3>
                    isOpen ? <ListofShips/> : null 
                }      
            </React.Fragment>    

I want to show all Cruise Lines from my seeds file.
Do I need to map over <h3> in order to display Cruise Lines? Does <h3> need to have a key?
isOpen ? <ListofShips/> : null  is there, so it goes to ListofShips when clicked

Comment: Yes, the `ship` variiable being used for button text is not defined.  And yes, it does seem you need to map over `this.state. cruiseHeaders` if you want multiple headers. After sifting through your source code you are not calling your API's correctly, in your API file `getShips` is commented out, so when `ListofShips` tries to call it when mounting it is also undefined.

Comment: It seems you want your APIs to also take data specific to fleets/etc, but then your endpoints are static. For the header mapping it looks like you want to pass a cruiseline value to the `ListofShips` so when *it* calls the endpoint it knows what ships to return.  There are a lot of missing data links between components.

Comment: Yes my API file https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/client/api/api.js did originally have getShips commented because I thought getListofShips would handle getting all the ships.
I have since realized that getShips is needed because when user clicks on ship from the List, it is goes to that one ship out of many ships on it's Cruise Line page.
I feel that I am getting closer to on the right track with functions, but I agree, my API's need to be better. May you please show me a code example of how I should do getListofShips in my API

Comment: Hi Drew

Please give me a good response as I have been bloody stuffed around on Stackoverflow a lot.
I have now got Cruise Line Headings showing on localhost:3000/cruiselines and this is my repo now https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines.

The problem now is that I am blocked on how to get only ships necessary for each Cruise Line, when you click on a Heading. Try it to see what I mean. Do you know how to get correct ships? Also when you click on a ship from that list, how can it go to a Review Page and to an id with the correct ship?.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginning, to set `isOpen` correctly on the state, modify the `onClick` function handler as this:

```
handleClick(event) {
  // this handleClick function should only handle the `isOpen` value in the state.
  // Any renders supposibly to be made on the `render` method instead.
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    shipsList: {
      isOpen: !prevState.shipsList.isOpen, //will reverse the prevState of isOpen.
    }
  }));
}
```

Now, Going to your `render`, we can handle the way you renderthe component that depends on the `this.state.shipsList.isOpen` this way:

```
render()    {
 //destructive declaration for isOpen from inside the shipsList in the state.
  const { shipsList: { isOpen } } = this.state;
  return  (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h3>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {ship.cruise_line}
        </button>
      </h3>
      {
        // Usually modals are shown at the bottom of the render return.
        // it's better to use tenary `val ? component : null` rather than: (val && component)
        // React accepts a component, or a null as return value, the second will return false if val was false.
        isOpen ? <OpenShipsList /> : null
      }
    </React.Fragment>    
  )
}
```

**PS:** Please follow the comments inside the code above of each line, they should be enough illustrating what happened, if something was ambiguos, just let me know.

Comment: I have changed my code in Visual Studio Code for https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines/client/components/CruiseListHeader.jsx using prevState like you have shown me. When I do a yarn dev on my iterm2 bash command line, in http://localhost:3000/#/cruiselines, I am getting ship is not defined at (CruiseListHeader.jsx:63) in console. I can see that this relates to {ship.cruise_line} within <button>. What code needs to be adjusted to stop this?
Also just wondering if prevState is the best way to handle state in this CruiseListHeader component?

Comment: My other Stack Overflow question "Expand/Collapse List for Headings using React
" follows on from this "onClick Cruise List Heading" one.
This ListofShips component comes into play when user clicks on a Cruise Line Heading and a list appears with Ship Hash Links. When user click on Ship Hash Link, it takes them to that ship on review page for it's Cruise Line, so just to be clear there could be more than one ship on review page for Cruise Line. Also wanting hovering effect on ship link with ship image. Still not sure how I can get this working, do you have any suggestions that may help?

Comment: I just thought I would mention that CruiseListHeader component comes from CruiseLines component, just in case you are wondering.

Comment: Hi Sultan

I sent you 3 messages regarding your reply to my question.
May you please reply to me when you can manage it.

Comment: I really apologies, didn't notice them, I will revise when I arrive home!

Comment: Rob, I am really trying to figure out where did -originally in your post- define `ship` inside your `render` method, it seems that you haven't done that part, anyways, does `ship` refer to an element inside `cruiseHeaders` array that you fetch at the `componentDidMount` via `setUpCruiseLines`, if true, there will be more than one `ship` an _Array_, correct?

Comment: Also, I have been reading lots of comments inside your components at the _robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines_ branch, it seems that your really need to start coding the stuff you want to do, and then bit by bit ask for a follow-up, what I mean is, do the first steps, make the mistake, and let's discuss what went wrong, wouldn't that be better consuming your Spare Time? put-in-practice is the best teacher you'll ever get.

Comment: Hi Sultan

I managed to get Cruise Line Headings showing on my Cruise Lines page.

Now, when I click on Cruise Line Heading to get a List of Ships it is not working and it comes up with an error that says ListofShips is not defined.

The question I need to ask you now is, is this happening because I have  getListofShips in my backend and ListofShips for my Component, so is it clashing?
Would it be better to call it getShipsList in the backend, so it works.

I'd appreciate your feedback on this, as we're here on this post to help each other out with their web development problems.