# Expand/Collapse List for Headings using React

Tags: reactjs

At the moment I am doing a website on cruise ships using React.

I am stumped on how I can display List of Ships based on their specific Cruise Lines, displaying across the page.

Note: 
This is on my Cruise Lines Page and this question is the next step, after my other stack overflow question "onClick for Cruise List Heading using React" [onClick for Cruise List Heading using React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140176/onclick-for-cruise-list-heading-using-react).

So as you can see from that question I am having an onClick for expanding or collapsing a List from a Heading.

I have been working on this here: https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/robs-shipslist-under-cruiselines.

Just wondering if anyone can give me advice on whether, I should be having a function, like I have to find ships names or if it is better have this controlled in the routes?

I am also looking to do hovering for when a user runs their mouse over a ship from a list and an image for that ship appears. 
To do this am I better to have a function like I have or control this process from another component for hovering?

Does anyone have any ideas that may help me solve this problem and make it work.

The following code is from my `ListofShips` component

```
import React from 'react'
import {getShips} from '../api/api'
import { HashLink as Link} from 'react-router-hash-link'
import CruiseListHeader from './CruiseListHeader' 

class ListofShips extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        //initialize shipsList as an empty array
        shipsList: []

      }
      this.setUpShips = this.setUpShips.bind(this)
      //this.onHover = this.onHover.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      console.log('cdm')
      this.setUpShips()
    }

    setUpShips() {
      console.log('getShips')
      getShips()  
      .then(res =>  {

        this.setState({
          shipsList: res  
        })
      })
    }

    //This is an onMouseOver event for when you run your mouse over ship in it's list
    onHover(event)  {

      getInitialState

      this.setState = {}
    }

    findShipNames(ship) {

      ship.cruise_line.id = ship.ship_name.id

      return ship.ship_name

      // This function helps display the Cruise Ships based on the Cruise Line

      // Example Code
      //   For Cruise_line === "Carnival"

      //   Ships Displayed =

      //   You have to group the Cruise Lines by their corresponding Ships, somehow

      //   return ship.ship_names

      //   this returns the Ship Names based on there Cruise Lines                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    }

  render()  {

    return  (

      <React.Fragment>

      <ol>
        {this.state.shipsList.map (ship => {  

          return   (
              // <li className = "shipsList" key = {ship.cruise_line} onMouseOver={this.onHover}><link smooth to = {`/cruiselines/${ship.cruise_line}#${ship.ship_name}`}>{this.findShipName(ship)}</link></li>
              <li className = "shipsList" key = {ship.cruise_line}><Link smooth to = {`/cruiselines/${ship.cruise_line}#${ship.ship_name}`}>{this.findShipName(ship)}</Link></li>

          )

          // I have to find a key that can display each ship name for each Headings Ships List.
          // The Link will be an Anchor Link to that specific ship, on it's Cruise Line Page.
          // Note: The Cruise Line Page, can have a Review for more than one ship and will be a Review Component.   

            // I would like to do a onMouse Hover function, so that when you run your mouse over ship in list a corresponding image appears

        })
        }
      </ol>

      </React.Fragment>
    )  
  }

}

export default ListofShips
```

I expect that a List of Ships for a specific cruise Line will show when I click on a Cruise Line Heading and when a list is showing and I click on the Heading, the List disappears. 
Also when I click on a ship from the List, the Link takes me to a review for that specific ship on it's Cruise Line Page.

Yarn dev is working OK on my command line, but I am getting the following in http://localhost:3000/#/cruiselines

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ship is not defined at CruiseListHeader.render (CruiseListHeader.jsx:63)
```

Comment: In your `CruiseListHeader` component, `<h3><button onClick = {this.handleClick}>{ship.cruise_line}</button></h3>` line has `ship` which is not defined in anywhere of the component. You should define `ship` or pass as a prop from parent component.

Comment: Hi Alpakyol,

I can see that the problem is happening with line 63 for ship.cruise_line in CruiseListHeader component, but why should that be a problem, because that is what I am wanting to display Cruise line Headings.

On my Reviews, branch https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/reviews/client/components/ListofShips.jsx, which is different than my current branch I am working on, I returned ship.ship_name and that displays well.

So I am puzzled on why this is causing a problem?
Can you please reply to me on this, as soon as you can.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what exactly the problem is. Error message clearly says that there is something wrong in `CruiseListHeader` component. In current revision of your question, you have not used `CruiseListHeader`. Also in shared github revision, there is no component called `CruiseListHeader` (AFAIK, I cannot see).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, OK I will make it clear it clear for you.

My first step is I want to get http://localhost:3000/#/cruiselines page showing.
Problem is error for line 63 in CruiseListHeader component, which is stopping page from showing.
What code needs to be changed or added to make this work?
You mentioned define ship or pass as a prop from parent component, I was a bit confused by this.

I have to get Cruise Line Headings showing to start with and then Ships List working with clicking after this. 

Hopefully this make it clear for you, what I am trying to ask you.

Comment: Hi Alpakyol
 
I managed to get Cruise Line Headings showing on my Cruise Lines page. 
Now, when I click on Cruise Line Heading to get a List of Ships it is not working and it comes up with an error that says ListofShips is not defined. 
The question I need to ask you now is, is this happening because I have getListofShips in my backend and ListofShips for my Component, so is it clashing? 
Would it be better to call it getShipsList in the backend, so it works. 
I'd appreciate your feedback on this, as we're here on this post to help each other out with their web development problems